# Why does Maven not find org.json JPMS automatic module?

Tags: java, maven, java-platform-module-system

I have a small test project, containing 2 files:

`pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20210307</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

and `src/main/java/module-info.java`:

```
module org.example.test {
    requires org.json;
}
```

When I compile with Temurin 17:

```
openjdk version "17" 2021-09-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17+35 (build 17+35)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17+35 (build 17+35, mixed mode, sharing)
```

And Maven 3.6.3 packaged with IntelliJ IDEA, I get this error:

```
src/main/java/module-info.java:[2,17] module not found: org.json
```

The `json-20210307.jar` file contains this line in `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`:

```
Automatic-Module-Name: org.json
```

What further do I need to do to use JPMS in Maven?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run
`mvn help:effective-pom` you will notice that the project uses the maven compiler version that may be a bit dated. Try explicitly using a newer version and see how it changes things:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version> <!-- current version -->
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it

Comment: I had to explicitly add the `maven-compiler-plugin` and bump it to `<version>3.11.0</version>` to get the org.json import to work.